# How to prevent double click on android push notification action

Tags: notifications, double, push

I have two buttons on push notification.
If user fast clicking on them, the services (onHandleIntent) starts twice.
How to prevent it.

Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP doesn't help.